# jQuery datepicker, using $(this) in defaultDate

Tags: jquery, datepicker

There is a form with a 'from' and 'until' date, with each a day, month and year box.
I want to fill the datePicker with each of these d-m-y values of the selected date ('from' or 'until').
This is what the script looks like:

```
$('.year').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    showOtherMonths: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonText: '',
    defaultDate: new Date(
        parseInt($('input[name="ydate'+$(this).attr('name').replace(/.date/, '')+'"]').val())
        ,parseInt($('input[name="mdate'+$(this).attr('name').replace(/.date/, '')+'"]').val())-1
        , parseInt($('input[name="ddate'+$(this).attr('name').replace(/.date/, '')+'"]').val())
    ),
    changeYear: true,
    onClose: function(dateText,picker) {
        var prefix = $(this).attr('name').replace(/.date/, '');

        $('input[name="ddate'+prefix+'"]').val( dateText.split(/\//)[1] );
        $('input[name="mdate'+prefix+'"]').val( dateText.split(/\//)[0] );
        $('input[name="ydate'+prefix+'"]').val( dateText.split(/\//)[2] );

    }
});
```

The onClose event fills the d-m-y inputfields just fine, but the defaultDate wont work like this.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the execution context is not changed, `this` still refers to the method's context in which the datepicker is initialized.

So the solution could be is to iterate through the set of `.year` elements using `.each()`, now inside the `each` handler `this` will refer to the current `.year` element.

```
$('.year').each(function () {
    var nm = $(this).attr('name').replace(/.date/, '');
    $(this).datepicker({
        inline: true,
        showOtherMonths: true,
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonText: '',
        defaultDate: new Date(
        parseInt($('input[name="ydate' + nm + '"]').val()), parseInt($('input[name="mdate' + nm + '"]').val()) - 1, parseInt($('input[name="ddate' + nm + '"]').val())),
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function (dateText, picker) {
            var prefix = $(this).attr('name').replace(/.date/, '');

            $('input[name="ddate' + prefix + '"]').val(dateText.split(/\//)[1]);
            $('input[name="mdate' + prefix + '"]').val(dateText.split(/\//)[0]);
            $('input[name="ydate' + prefix + '"]').val(dateText.split(/\//)[2]);

        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I was a bit confused why it worked in the onClose event. It works now :-)